# jQuery select parent a of an image

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select the anchor tag and add a target attribute. When it is wrapped in a image with the class size-thumbnail. Anyone know why this wont work?

```
<a href="example"><img class="size-thumbnail" src="example"></a>
```

jquery

```
$('.size-thumbnail:parent').attr('target','_blank');
```

Comment: I believe the `:parent` selector in this case will give you every `.size-thumbnail` that has child elements. Since images can't have children, this wouldn't ever work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('a').has('img.size-thumbnail').attr('target','_blank');
```

or

```
$('a.has(img.size-thumbnail)').attr('target','_blank');
```

Answer (score 3):

You have the meaning of [`:parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/) backwards — it selects elements which *are* parents, not the *parent of* the selected element.  Try this instead:

```
$('.size-thumbnail').parent().attr('target','_blank');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to traverse up the Dom Tree

Example:

```
var Link = $("img.size-thumbnail").parent();
```

And then apply the methods such as `attr` on the `Link` variable like so:

```
var Link = $("img.size-thumbnail").parent();
Link.attr("target","_blank");
```

Answer (score 1):

All answers here seem ok,but you can do it in reverse:

```
$('a:has(.size-thumbnail)').attr("target","_blank");
```

you can do that since nested anchor tags are not valid ;) so the image is always a child in an anchor and not in multiple anchors.

Comment: Performance shouldn't matter unless there are a very large number of such images, but `.parent()` is actually quite a bit faster than `:has`.  jQuery optimizes `.parent()` using the DOM `.parentNode` property (a static lookup), whereas `:has` requires subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how the [`:parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/) works.

The `:parent` means select elements that are parents to other elements..

You need

```
$('.size-thumbnail').parent().attr('target','_blank');
```